# Kafka mirrormaker do not start

Tags: apache-kafka

Im in the process of upgrading our cluster. However Im having issues trying to make the mirrormakers run.

So this machines have kafka-brokers and kafka-mirrormakers running. They have separate init scripts.

The brokers currently are using version 10.1.1.1 and mirrormakers are using version 0.8.2-beta.

Both of them have their own config files and locations

for example brokers are installed in /server/kafka/
mirrormakers are installed under /opt/kafka_mirrormaker.

Here the config lines for **brokers** following what the upgrade process explained:

> inter.broker.protocol.version=0.10.1
>   log.message.format.version=0.8.2

and for **mirrormakers**:

> inter.broker.protocol.version=0.8.2
>   log.message.format.version=0.8.2

So I was testing to upgrade this to 10.2.1 I tried the upgrade in one host. 
Broker is running fine after I applied the upgrade version 10.2.1 however the mirrormaker dies right away when I tried to start it.

I see this exception on the logs

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.main(MirrorMaker.scala:309)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker.main(MirrorMaker.scala)
Exception in thread "MirrorMakerShutdownHook" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.cleanShutdown(MirrorMaker.scala:399)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$$anon$2.run(MirrorMaker.scala:222)
tail: kafka-mirrormaker-repl-sjc2-to-hkg1.out: file truncated
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.main(MirrorMaker.scala:309)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker.main(MirrorMaker.scala)
Exception in thread "MirrorMakerShutdownHook" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.cleanShutdown(MirrorMaker.scala:399)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$$anon$2.run(MirrorMaker.scala:222)
```

and this one

```
[2017-05-18 17:02:27,936] ERROR Exception when starting mirror maker. (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Missing required configuration "bootstrap.servers" which has no default value.
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigDef.parse(ConfigDef.java:436)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:56)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.<init>(AbstractConfig.java:63)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig.<init>(ProducerConfig.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:191)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMakerProducer.<init>(MirrorMaker.scala:694)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$.main(MirrorMaker.scala:236)
    at kafka.tools.MirrorMaker.main(MirrorMaker.scala)
```

This bootstrap error is kind of weird due to this already config. The server.properties has localhost:9292 configured as the bootstrap.server

To upgrade this I did broker and mirrormaker at the same time. Im not sure if I should first upgrade all the brokers first and then the mirrormakers.

Any suggestions. Should I follow the same procedure, upgrade first all brokers and then all mirrormakers. once they are upgrade bump the protocols in server.properties. Even though when it seems that the documentation kind of doesnt imply that: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#upgrade

Answer (score 0):

This has being solved.
The reason why they were not starting was due to the options on the configuration files change or were not properly configure